# TSQL - Parent Child (1 to zero/many) Grouping/Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

**Code (Sample Data Staging):**

```
DECLARE @Emp TABLE
    (
        [EId] INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
      , [FN]  NVARCHAR(50)
      , [LN]  NVARCHAR(50)
    ) ;
DECLARE @EmpPhCont TABLE
    (
        [EId]       INT
      , [PhType]    VARCHAR(10)
      , [PhNum]     VARCHAR(16)
      , [PhExt]     VARCHAR(10)
      , [IsMain]    BIT
      , [CreatedOn] DATETIME
    ) ;

INSERT INTO @Emp
VALUES
    ( N'Emp1', N'Emp1' )
  , ( N'Emp2', N'Emp2' )
  , ( N'Emp3', N'Emp3' )
  , ( N'Emp4', N'Emp4' )
  , ( N'Emp5', N'Emp5' )
  , ( N'Emp6', N'Emp5' ) ;

INSERT INTO @EmpPhCont
VALUES
    ( 1, 'Home', '111111111', NULL, 0, '2020-01-01 00:00:01' )
  , ( 1, 'Mobile', '222222222', NULL, 1, '2020-01-01 00:00:02' )
  , ( 1, 'Work', '333333333', NULL, 0, '2020-01-01 00:00:03' )

  , ( 2, 'Work', '444444444', '567', 1, '2020-01-01 00:00:04' )
  , ( 2, 'Mobile', '555555555', NULL, 0, '2020-01-01 00:00:05' )
  , ( 2, 'Mobile', '454545454', NULL, 0, '2020-01-01 00:00:06' )

  , ( 3, 'Home', '777777777', NULL, 0, '2020-01-01 00:00:07' )
  , ( 3, 'Mobile', '888888888', NULL, 1, '2020-01-01 00:00:08' )
  , ( 3, 'Mobile', '12121212', NULL, 0, '2020-01-01 00:00:09' )

  , ( 4, 'Work', '101010101', '111', 1, '2020-01-01 00:00:10' )
  , ( 4, 'Work', '101010102', '232', 0, '2020-01-01 00:00:11' )

  , ( 5, 'Work', '545454545', '456', 0, '2020-01-01 00:00:10' )
  , ( 5, 'Work', '456456456', NULL, 1, '2020-01-01 00:00:11' )  ;
```

**Description:**

@Emp is the sample Employee table (Unique Employee records).

- EId = Employee Id
- FN = First Name
- LN = Last Name

@EmpPhCont is the sample Employee Phone Contact table (Each Emp from @Emp table can have zero, one, or multiple phone numbers here - unique by Emp/Type).

- PhType = Phone Type (home, mobile, work, and etc)
- PhNum = Phone Number
- PhExt = Phone Extension (mostly available for "Work" PhType)
- IsMain = Is it main contact number. Each employee with a phone num will have exactly 1 record marked as IsMain.
- CreatedOn = Date the record was created

**Goal:**

To output 1 record per employee with the following Columns

> EId | HomeNum | MobileNum | WorkNum | WorkNumExt | MainPhType

*Rules:*

Return all EId for all records from @Emp, whether they have a @EmpPhCont record or not.

For each emp that has @EmpPhCont record avail, return the newest created PhNum and PhExt for the corresponding PhType, *UNLESS* an older record for the same Emp/PhType is marked as IsMain = 1 (For any emp, for whichever PhType, if IsMain = 1, always return that PhNum and PhExt value).

**Expected Output:**

```
EId HomeNum     MobileNum   WorkNum     WorkNumExt  MainPhType
1   111111111   222222222   333333333   NULL        Mobile
2   NULL        454545454   444444444   567         Work
3   777777777   888888888   NULL        NULL        Mobile
4   NULL        NULL        101010102   111         Work
5   NULL        NULL        456456456   NULL        Work
6   NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

*My unsuccessful try:*

```
SELECT      [EM].[EId]
          , MAX ( IIF([PH].[PhType] = 'Home', [PH].[PhNum], NULL)) AS [HomePhNum]
          , MAX ( IIF([PH].[PhType] = 'Mobile', [PH].[PhNum], NULL)) AS [MobilePhNum]
          , MAX ( IIF([PH].[PhType] = 'Work', [PH].[PhNum], NULL)) AS [WorkPhNum]
FROM        @Emp AS [EM]
LEFT JOIN   @EmpPhCont AS [PH]
ON          [EM].[EId] = [PH].[EId]
GROUP BY    [EM].[EId] ;
```

Comment: For EId 3 why do you only get one mobile number? And what is the logic for why you get the one that you do? I think you need to look into ROW_NUMBER first so that you can get the correct row for each EId and PhoneType...hint (PARTITION BY)

Comment: @SeanLange Question already states the rule for that: *"return the **newest** created PhNum and PhExt for the corresponding PhType, **UNLESS** an older record for the same Emp/PhType is marked as **IsMain = 1**"*

Comment: @Andreas oops missed that. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function inside a `CTE` to get the rows from `@EmpPhCont` that you want returned and join this `CTE` to `@Emp`:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by [EId], [PhType] order by [IsMain] desc, [CreatedOn] desc) rn
  from @EmpPhCont
)
select e.[EId],
  max(case when c.[PhType] = 'Home' then c.[PhNum] end) HomeNum,
  max(case when c.[PhType] = 'Mobile' then c.[PhNum] end) MobileNum,
  max(case when c.[PhType] = 'Work' then c.[PhNum] end) WorkNum,
  max(case when c.[PhType] = 'Work' then c.[PhExt] end) WorkNumExt,
  max(case when c.[IsMain] = 1 then c.[PhType] end) MainPhType 
from @Emp e left join cte c
on c.[EId] = e.[EId] and c.rn = 1
group by e.[EId]
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=848a030ae7d793dabcab0b041d489ae1).
Results:

```
> EId | HomeNum   | MobileNum | WorkNum   | WorkNumExt | MainPhType
> --: | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :--------- | :---------
>   1 | 111111111 | 222222222 | 333333333 | null       | Mobile    
>   2 | null      | 454545454 | 444444444 | 567        | Work      
>   3 | 777777777 | 888888888 | null      | null       | Mobile    
>   4 | null      | null      | 101010101 | 111        | Work      
>   5 | null      | null      | 456456456 | null       | Work      
>   6 | null      | null      | null      | null       | null
```

Comment: Need to limit `c.[PhExt]` to `c.[PhType] = 'Work'`. --- Still, +1 for nice concise solution.

Comment: I think that *mostly available for "Work" PhType* would cover it, but I will edit.

Comment: "mostly" <> "only" 

Comment: Was about to post a nearly identical solution. Conditional aggregation wins again.

Comment: Thank you @forpas for this concise solution. Interesting approach with the R_Num window function. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would implement that using `APPLY`:

```sql
SELECT EId, HomeNum, MobileNum, WorkNum, WorkNumExt
     , COALESCE(HomeMain, MobileMain, WorkMain) AS MainPhType
  FROM Emp e
 OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT TOP 1 c.[PhNum] AS HomeNum
               , CASE WHEN c.[IsMain] = 1 THEN 'Home' END AS HomeMain
            FROM EmpPhCont c
           WHERE c.[EId] = e.[EId]
             AND c.[PhType] = 'Home'
           ORDER BY c.[IsMain] DESC, c.[CreatedOn] DESC
       ) home
 OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT TOP 1 c.[PhNum] AS MobileNum
               , CASE WHEN c.[IsMain] = 1 THEN 'Mobile' END AS MobileMain
            FROM EmpPhCont c
           WHERE c.[EId] = e.[EId]
             AND c.[PhType] = 'Mobile'
           ORDER BY c.[IsMain] DESC, c.[CreatedOn] DESC
       ) mobile
 OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT TOP 1 c.[PhNum] AS WorkNum
               , c.[PhExt] AS WorkNumExt
               , CASE WHEN c.[IsMain] = 1 THEN 'Work' END AS WorkMain
            FROM EmpPhCont c
           WHERE c.[EId] = e.[EId]
             AND c.[PhType] = 'Work'
           ORDER BY c.[IsMain] DESC, c.[CreatedOn] DESC
       ) work
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/29618/4) for demo.

*Output*

```sql
EId | HomeNum   | MobileNum | WorkNum   | WorkNumExt | MainPhType
1   | 111111111 | 222222222 | 333333333 | (null)     | Mobile
2   | (null)    | 454545454 | 444444444 | 567        | Work
3   | 777777777 | 888888888 | (null)    | (null)     | Mobile
4   | (null)    | (null)    | 101010101 | 111        | Work
5   | (null)    | (null)    | 456456456 | (null)     | Work
6   | (null)    | (null)    | (null)    | (null)     | (null)
```

*Note:* This solution will only be viable for large data sets if the `EmpPhCont` table has an index on `[EId], [PhType]`, otherwise it'll be too slow.

Comment: Even with an index this will be slower than conditional aggregation because it has to hit the same table multiple times.

Comment: @SeanLange True, for a full dump of the employee table, as is the case here, but if the employees are filtered, this solution may be faster. It's a good alternative, with a more *directed* approach.

Comment: Agreed. I certainly didn't say it was not a good alternative. Always good to find multiple ways to solve the same problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andreas for this solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

row_number(), outer apply and aggregation:

```
select *
from @Emp as e
outer apply
(
    select 
          MAX ( case when d.[PhType] = 'Home' then d.[PhNum] end) AS [HomePhNum]
        , MAX ( case when d.[PhType] = 'Mobile' then d.[PhNum] end) AS [MobilePhNum]
        , MAX ( case when d.[PhType] = 'Work' then d.[PhNum] end) AS [WorkPhNum]
        , MAX ( case when d.[PhType] = 'Work' then d.[PhExt] end) AS [WorkNumExt]
        , MAX ( case when IsMain = 1 then d.[PhType] end) AS MainPhType --work is max if both mob&work as set as main..
    from
    (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by PhType order by IsMain DESC, CreatedOn DESC) as rownum
    from @EmpPhCont as p
    where p.EId = e.EId
    ) as d
    where d.rownum = 1  
) as ph;
```

Comment: Thank you @lptr for a CTE-less-variant of the solution. Cheers!